# ValueError: No axis named 'inp' for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe,df

```
        Date        inp   name   
    0  2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC 
    1  2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC      
    2  2017-08-08  2.3.6  TAC         
    3  2017-08-22  2.5.9  TTT         
    4  2017-09-23  0.8.0  TAC         
    5  2017-10-09  2.3.6  ABC         
    6  2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC
    7  2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC                  
    8  2017-10-23  0.8.0  TAC         
    9  2017-11-08  6.2.6  ABC
```

then I want to count the occurences in columns: 'name' and 'inp' by grouping on a monthly basis. The dataframe,df2 should look like this:

```
        Date       inp   name      count
      2017-08     2.3.6  ABC         2
      2017-08     2.3.6  TAC         1
      2017-08     2.5.9  TTT         1
      2017-09     0.8.0  TAC         1
      2017-10     2.3.6  ABC         1
      2017-10     2.3.6  TAC         2
      2017-10     0.8.0  TAC         1
      2017-11     6.2.6  ABC         1
```

Then, a new dataframe,df3 like this:this is done by grouping on a monthly basis  to sum the counts of occurences(inp,name) on a monthly basis, and also changing the date index into words of the month, then pivoting

```
   Index      2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC  2.5.9TTT  0.8.0TAC  6.2.6ABC         
   August      2          1        1         0           0
  September    0          0        0         1           0
  October      1          2        0         1           0
  November     0          0        0         0           1
```

but I have code like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Date','inp','name'])
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S 0"')
df = df.set_index(['Date'])
print(df)
df = df.loc['2017-08-01':'2017-11-30']

df2 = (df.groupby(df.index.date,'inp')['name']
     .value_counts()
     .rename_axis(('Date','inp','name'))
     .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df2)
#Sum the total number of  unique (name,inp) associated per month     
df2.Date= pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df3 = df2.groupby( [pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M'),'inp','name']) ["count"].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
df3.index = df3.index.strftime('%B')
print(df3)
```

but I keep getting :

```
ValueError: No axis named inp for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Incase I want to remove columns that have more than 2 zeros. for example, a new dataframe like this, how do I go about it?

```
    Index      2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC       0.8.0TAC           
   August      2          1                 0           
  September    0          0                 1           
  October      1          2                 1           
  November     0          0                 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use faster solution with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) instead `df['Date'].dt.date` first with `[]` for list in `groupby`:

```
df2 = (df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.floor('D'),'inp'])['name']
     .value_counts()
     .rename_axis(('Date','inp','name'))
     .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df2)
        Date    inp name  count
0 2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC      2
1 2017-08-08  2.3.6  TAC      1
2 2017-08-22  2.5.9  TTT      1
3 2017-09-23  0.8.0  TAC      1
4 2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC      2
5 2017-10-09  2.3.6  ABC      1
6 2017-10-23  0.8.0  TAC      1
7 2017-11-08  6.2.6  ABC      1
```

Then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by second and third level and replace `NaN` to `0` by `.unstack(level=[1,2], fill_value=0)`:

```
df3 = (df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M'),'inp','name'])["count"]
          .sum()
          .unstack(level=[1,2], fill_value=0))
df3.columns = df3.columns.map(''.join)
df3.index = df3.index.strftime('%B')
print (df3)
           2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC  2.5.9TTT  0.8.0TAC  6.2.6ABC
August            2         1         1         0         0
September         0         0         0         1         0
October           1         2         0         1         0
November          0         0         0         0         1
```

And last remove columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`:

```
df4 = df3.loc[:, df3.eq(0).sum() <= 2]
#same as
#df4 = df3.loc[:, (df3 == 0).sum() <= 2]
print (df4)
           2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC  0.8.0TAC
August            2         1         0
September         0         0         1
October           1         2         1
November          0         0         0
```

Comment: thank you for this! but however, it does not replace nan with 0. The dataframe is still showing Nan so the df4 = df3.loc[:, df3.eq(0).sum() <= 2] didn't remove the columns

Comment: I think you need fillna(0) after unstack() function. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jezrael  to remove  by row values, I tried using `df.loc [df.index[(df.eq(0).sum()==3)], 10] `      but I get 
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 78 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1590

Comment: Do you need `df[(df.eq(0).sum(axis=1)==3)]`, sum per rows and filter?

Comment: thanks a lot,it did work!!! but can't I also filter columns based on two conditions   `dfT =df.loc[:, df.eq(0).sum() <=2 or df.max()<10] `    but I get this error:ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: It is possible, but need `|` and `()` like `dfT =df.loc[:, (df.eq(0).sum() <=2) | (df.max()<10)]`

Comment: Thanks a bunch bro